# Prevent MPMoviePlayerController from stopping Background Music

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've just got one seemingly small problem. I'm using a MPMovieViewController to loop a small non-audio video file. When I enter the ViewController which contains it, it disables any background music, which is completely unnecessary. I have tried AVPlayer but it does the same plus looping seems particularly difficult with it.

Code for the MPMovieController is nothing special:

```
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoFile ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128);

[self.movieView addSubview:player.view];
player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[player prepareToPlay];
```

To disable the music interruption for the video playback or for the whole app would be both fine, I don't use any audio in it.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your audio session setup prevents what you have in mind. Make sure you read and understand the developer [reference on Audio Session setup](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html).

Comment: I was looking for the answer to this question as well. The question is a year old now and the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22077019