# Prevent MPMoviePlayerController from Interrupting Device's Main Audio

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've added an introductory video to my application using MPMoviePlayerController.  The video plays as expected. However, the video does not - and should not - have sound BUT, if the user is listening to music (for example) on their device and then opens my application, the music stops playing as my video starts playing.  Since my video has no sound, I'd like the playing of my video to NOT interrupt the main audio on the device.

I've looked through MPMoviePlayerController class, and don't see any clues. Is there a way to do this? Here is my code:

```
- (void)setUpVideoPlayer
{

  NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"introVideo" ofType:@"MP4"];
  NSURL *videoUrl =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoUrl];

  player.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
  player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

  [player prepareToPlay];

  [player setShouldAutoplay:YES];
  [player setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
  [player setFullscreen:YES];
  [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
  [player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
  [player play];

  player.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  NSLayoutConstraint *playerWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:player.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
  NSLayoutConstraint *playerHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:player.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
  NSLayoutConstraint *playerTop = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:player.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
  NSLayoutConstraint *playerLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:player.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

  [self.view addSubview:player.view];
  [self.view addConstraints:@[playerWidth, playerHeight, playerTop, playerLeft]];

  _player = player;

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answered my own question:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioSession.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];

  //do other stuff
}
```