# How can I prevent video recording with AVFoundation from interrupting any global audio that is currently playing (Swift)?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have successfully implemented valid and working AVFoundation video recording functionality into my application. That said, any playing audio e.g. Apple Music or a YouTube video playing in the background is interrupted / immediately paused whenever the video recording begins.

My question is: How could I allow the globally-playing audio to continue to play without interruption when recording video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by adapting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073349/prevent-mpmovieplayercontroller-from-interrupting-devices-main-audio) to Swift.

I was doing this to prevent a silent tutorial video in my app from interrupting any currently playing audio. Setting the AVAudioSession category to "ambient" using the [setCategory(_:mode:options:) method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1771734-setcategory) seems to be the key here.

Apple [seems to suggest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession) using this method within the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, but I think their example is targeted towards audio apps. So depending on your needs, you may want to put it there.

Here's the adapted code, I placed it within the view controller that is showing the video:

```
import AVFoundation

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```